xlwings python fails to read excel data
I am trying this code because it can read the data with an open excel workbook.
import xlwings as xw

xlsfile = r'C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Dokumente\20241023-1904097928-umsatz.xlsx'
workbook = xw.Book(xlsfile)
ws = workbook.sheets[4]
tbl = ws.api.ListObjects(1) # or .ListObjects(1)
rng = ws.range(tbl.range.address) # get range from table address
df = rng.options(pd.DataFrame, header=True).value # load range to dataframe

This code runs now for 10 minutes and consumes over 1 GB of memory.
Excel is frozen. The table to load contains about 2500 rows. Not much data, should be loadable in < 1s.
What is going wrong?

Your code will probably hang on the 'rng' selection. 
However this line is not necessary.
Try this instead;
Note ws.tables[0].name will exclude the Table header from the range. ws.tables[0].range will include the whole table with header.
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd


xlsfile = r'C:\Users\matth\OneDrive\Dokumente\20241023-1904097928-umsatz.xlsx'
workbook = xw.Book(xlsfile)
ws = workbook.sheets[4]

### Create Dataframe
## All rows excluding the Header row
df = ws.range(ws.tables[0].name).options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=0).value
## All rows
df = ws.range(ws.tables[0].range).options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=1).value

print(df)

